# Registering an interop dll on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: dll, com, interop, activex, windows-server-2008-r2

I have searched all over StackOverflow and the internet for help with this.  This is a very commonly asked question and I have tried everything that I could find and still no success.

The problem is that my company wrote their own encryption dll several years ago.  It is now considered obsolete in the company but we are a small branch of a larger corporation and we use this on our classic ASP intranet web site.

We are in the early stages of migrating our web site to a Windows Server 2008 R2 virtual server.

Most every web site I found said the same thing.  Go to C:\Windows\SysWOW64 and run regsvr32.exe in a command box.  I have done this with the dll in a separate folder and I have done this after the dll has been copied to the SysWOW64 folder.

Each time I get an error message and the messages are not always the same.  The message du jour that I am getting is:

```
The module "Interop.MyEncryptionTool.dll" was loaded by the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.

Make sure that "Interop.MyEncryptionTool.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX and then try again.
```

I do not have the source code of the dll nor do I think anyone in the company has it.  I wrote my own encryption dll in VS 2008 in VB.net and it works fine but we decided that even though the company considers their dll obsolete it is still a standard.  The company never created an updated version to replace this dll.

At this point I am wondering not so much how to do this but is it even possible.  Did 2008 R2 drop compatibility with older Active-X, COM or COM+ dll's?

Comment: You are trying to register the completely wrong DLL.  The Interop dll is only meant for a .NET program, helping it to use the COM server.  The Regsvr32.exe command must be issued on the unmanaged DLL, whatever its name might be.  Talk to somebody that knows about this.

Comment: Thanks Hans.  I didn't realize that Interop dlls were .Net.  I written a few dll's before but I am not expert on them.  I should be able to change my searches to look for .net dlls and find information on that.